# Improve redundant attribute expression when selecting element in CSS

Tags: css, dry

I have a quick question that I honestly can't find an answer for because I don't really know how to word it... Silly, I know.

Anyway, I have this large, really ugly block of code that. It serves the role of putting an icon in the `::before` pseudoelement to indicate a file type. I currently am just selecting by file type in the "`data-path`" attribute (which contains the full path and subsequently, the file extension). I feel like there has to be a way to make the selector or expression better.

So what I currently have is this (cut for brevity):

```css
...
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".png"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".jpg"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".jpeg"] > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".gif"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".tiff"] > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".webp"] > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".bmp"]  > .nav-file-tag::before {
  content: '️ '; 
}
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".pdf"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".docx"] > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".doc"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".txt"]  > .nav-file-tag::before {
  content: ' '; 
}
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".csv"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".xlsx"] > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".xls"]  > .nav-file-tag::before {
  content: ' ';
}
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".mp4"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".mov"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".avi"]  > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".webm"] > .nav-file-tag::before,
.nav-file-title[data-path$=".flv"]  > .nav-file-tag::before {
  content: '️ ';
}
...
```

Does anyone know a way to dry up this code?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `make the selector or expression better`? Do you mean to make it shorter? As a side note: adding emojis into the `content` attribute inside pseudo elements like this is not accessible and makes for an awful experience on screen readers

Comment: As for the emojis, I'm aware. I'm not going to be doing this as final production code, this is just an example, and shows up in browser fine.

Comment: That's part of the problem... I'm not really sure how to word this question properly. I just want to not repeat myself as much. As you can see, I have a separate line for each file extension. I'm just wondering if there is a way to shorten the selector into one line, e.g. into some sort of regex e.g.  `\.mp4|\.mov|\.avi|\.webm` etc.

Comment: To my understanding, the "?=" operator is the extent of CSS's regular expression parsing, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. CSS is build to do it this way.

Comment: You can use Sass or Scss to do this for you though